# Firefox and Chrome 3D transforms glitches

Tags: css, animation, transform, transition

I created flipping cards that based on CSS transitions and transforms, but it has a few rendering glitches in various browsers when card is flipping.

[Live example](http://6.puzzle-english.com/_cards/)

In Firefox the top card which is animates overlaps by the under cards regardless of specified `z-index`.
In Chrome the card is flickering when animates.

`backface-visibility:hidden` and `transform-style:preserve-3d` are specified, and everything else seems to be okay.

Maybe there's some other CSS/JS hack?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have to move the back card 1px in the z direction to stay over the front card. (translateZ(1px);)

More or less the same that you tried to do with z-index, but in 3D space.

I tried to do it in the live example, but there was way too much code to find it easily. You should give simplified examples to help people help you

OK, finally got it. It wasn't the base div but the figure:

```
.card-wrap figure {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's realy helps. Even with `translateZ(0px)`. So now it's working great in Firefox. In Chrome it's still blinking :(. Sorry for a mess of code, thought it wouldn't be a problem to add css through Firebug or other debugger.

Comment: At last I did understand your code. Added more specific answer.

Comment: I added `translateZ(1px)` to `<figure>` tag and now it is not blibking anymore in Chrome! For Firefox it should be added to the `div.card` tag instead. So the same solution helps for both browsers! Thank you, thank you, thanks!!! ;)